# Why does 'new Function' not work as eval?

Tags: javascript, function, eval, calculation, ecmascript-2016

I have for example code (with 'new Function') which will open an alert window:

```
   new Function`alert(1)`; // Works OK
```

The same code on `eval`

```
   eval('alert(1)'); // Works OK
```

---

But why if I use calculating:

```
 new Function`2+2`; // It does not work. It shows {}
```

Eval works correctly:

```
   eval('2+2'); // Works OK , will be 4
```

---

Why is the code

```
 new Function`2+2`;
```

not working?

Comment: Do you mean `new Function("2+2");` with parentheses?  You aren't actually calling anything if you don't use the parentheses.

Comment: @zero298 wrong! This is correct code in es6/7. With ES6/7 you can call a function passing it a template literal.

Comment: @Megajin Can you show documentation for that?  I have never seen that used and I can't find that on the MDN documentation: [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: [Tagged Templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates)

Comment: @zero298 the relevant part is "tagged templates".

Comment: I think it's impossible to use call with template string, it works only with `new Function('return 1+1')()`

Comment: @KirkLarkin interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's impossible to use a function call with a template string for calculating. It works only with single quotes or double quotes.

```js
const result = new Function('return 2+2')();

console.log(result); // 4
```

Comment: I can prove that you are wrong, it is possible with tagged templates. Look at my answer.

Comment: @Megajin , thanks for your answer, but I wanna use new Function without eval

Comment: Ok, I can prove that there is one way. Give me some minutes I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**The initial question was:**

> Why is the code: new Function`2+2`;  not working?

To simply explain this, you have to look up what parameters the JavaScript `Function` constructor will take in: [MDN Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).
As you can see, the desired inputs are strings:

```
const sum = new Function('a', 'b', 'return a + b');

console.log(sum(2, 6));
// Expected output: 8
```

If you do:

```
new Function`2+2`;
```

You will simply create an anonymous instance without any values to use or return values. That is why the output will be `anonymous {}`.

> I think it's impossible to use function call with template string for
> calculating, it works only with single quotes or double quotes

I can prove that it will work. There are different ways to approach this issue:

```
new Function('return arguments[1]')`${2+2}`; // Outputs 4
new Function`return Object.entries(arguments)[0]`(2+2); // Outputs ['0',4]
```

I think you can now understand how to work with the `Function` constructor and `tagged templates`. The important part is working with the arguments object and access your desired return value.

The old answer with eval:

```
const myFunc = evalStr => console.log(eval(evalStr[0]));
myFunc`2+2`;
```

For more information:

- [Function - constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)
- [Argument object](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)
- [Tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals)
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I wanna use new Function without eval

Comment: I did add more detail into my answer, it should be clear now =).

Comment: new Function('return arguments[1]')`${2+2}`; this will be executed at once(when you send an argument), it will be interpreted as new Function('return arguments[1]')`${4}` , this does not make sense; 2+2 should send as string not as a number 4

Comment: You could do `'${2+2}'` or `'2+2'` and interprete it in arguments. Everything is possible, I just wanted to show you that you "can" use template literals. By the way this `new Function('return 2+2')` will be interpreted as `function() {return 2+2;}` so it is the same as shown by me but with template literals.

Answer (score 0):

When you use backticks in JavaScript, it is called template literals.  You can see [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for details.

Basically, the string you pass to the function in backticks, is passed as parameters to the function, of which you haven't defined a function.  When using backticks with a function, it is called a tagged-template-literal.  You will need to first define the function (how to do math on string passed in).  In your case, you want to use *eval*, so your tag should look like this:

```
const myTaggedTemplateLiteral = (evalStrings) => eval(evalStrings[0]);
myTaggedTemplateLiteral`2+2` // 4
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I wanna use new Function without eval

Answer (score -2):

You should out return before the calculation:

```js
var a = new Function("return 2+2");
```

If you want make it dynamic, just add the arguments

```js
var a = new Function("x", "y", "return x+y");
```

Comment: please remove this answer!

this code was copy pasted from my comment

Comment: Code only answers are bad practice, you should at least explain what you are doing. [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)